# Regular expression: matching word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble understanding the way boundaries work.

Say I'm trying to scrape an HTML string which contains:

```
<caption>foo</caption><caption>bar</caption>
```

Say I want to match each

> `<caption>..</caption>`

segment? I tried `/<caption>.*</caption>` but I guess because its greedy it just takes the whole line..how do I workaround that so I have two separate matches?

Comment: As usual, with a lazy quantifier: `/<caption>.*?<\/caption>/`. Or `/<caption>[^]*?<\/caption>/`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that existed!!